# How to view dataframe on button click ipywidgets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to display my dataframe on button click as i would normally in a jupyter cell by using `df.head()` . I want the button click to view the data frame based on the currency parameter which the user can choose. Not sure where I am going wrong.

````
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as ipy
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
%matplotlib inline

w_Currency = ipy.Dropdown(
    options=['usd', 'eur', 'jpy', 'gbp'],
    value='usd',
    description='Currency:',
    disabled=False,
)
w_CheckData = ipy.Button(
    value=False,
    description='Check Data',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='',
    tooltip='Check data',
    icon='check' 
)

# Get a list of the top 100 based on market cap
coins = cg.get_coins_markets(vs_currency = currencyWidget.value)
# Create a dataframe from the dictionary defined above
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(coins)
# 100 rows × 26 columns is the dimension of this dataframe

def on_button_clicked(df):
    # View head
    df.head()
    
w_CheckData.on_click(on_button_clicked(df))
items = [w_Currency, w_CheckData]
box = ipy.Box(children=items)
box ```
````

Comment: I can't run your code, can you construct a simplified dataframe from a dictionary, and also include your imports?

Comment: I have added the imports

Comment: I think you are just missing `display(df.head()` instead of `df.head()`

Comment: When I do that I get ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable``` so not sure

Comment: OK you have a common problem here. `w_CheckData.on_click(on_button_clicked)` is what you need, not `w_CheckData.on_click(on_button_clicked(df))` You need to pass the function to call, not the return value of a called function.

Comment: same error bro, I think I am just going to go down another road.